# Как послать с сервера команду во фронт, чтобы обновить значение определённого компонента?

Tags: javascript, php, клиент-сервер

Допустим есть работники, которые выполняют работу, и менеджер, который за этим следит. Каждый раз когда работник сделал задание оно появляется у менеджера, чтобы он его принял. Как сделать, чтобы в реальном времени на странице менеджера появлялись эти новые задания, как только они появляются?

Мне в голову приходит способ делать запрос каждые несколько секунд к бэкенду, но как-то страшно представить такое количество запросов каждые несколько секунд, поступающее от каждого менеджера.

Можно ли как-то отправлять команду с сервера напрямую странице менеджера, с определённой командой?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Способов несколько, в зависимости от тяжести случая можно выбрать тот, который Вам больше всего понравится или который будет проще реализовать.

Везде есть свои за и против.

**1. Самый древний способ, и самый простой - Polling**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> - клиент подключается и говорит: `Привет, я Вася, Как там дела?`
> - сервер **СРАЗУ** отвечает: `С твоего последнего визита ничего интересного не произошло` / `Произошли такие-то события` и закрывает соединение
> - клиент отправляет новый запрос

Я уверен добрая половина интернета работает таким способом.

**2. Тоже вариант из прошлого, посложнее - Long Polling**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> - клиент подключается и говорит: `Привет, я Вася, Сообщи когда что-то произойдет`
> - сервер **ЖДЕТ** пока произойдет событие, отвечает `Событие произошло`, закрывает соединение.
> - клиент отправляет новый запрос

**3. Server Sent Events** - обеспечивает отправку сообщений в **ОДНУ СТРОНУ**, от сервера клиенту.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> - клиент подключается и говорит: `Привет, я Вася, жду сообщений` и больше **не может отправлять сообщения**
> - сервер **ЖДЕТ** пока произойдет событие, отвечает `Событие произошло`, и не закрывает соединение после отправки

Протокол обмена - обычный текст разделенный делимитерами.

**4. WebSocket** - обеспечивает отправку сообщений в **ОБЕ СТОРОНЫ**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> - клиент подключается и спрашивает: `Привет, я Вася, жду сообщений` и **может отправлять еще сообщения в любое время**
> - сервер **ЖДЕТ** пока произойдет событие, отвечает `Событие произошло`, и не закрывает соединение после отправки

[Протокол обмена](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers) - более сложный чем у SSE, тут уже есть заголовок и другие тонкости.

Со стороны сервера, [реализация SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) значительно проще, чем реализация вебсокетов. Это на случай если Ваш веб сервер не умеет что то из выше перечисленного из коробки.

Comment: Ваш ответ правильный, но если обратить внимание на то какие теги у данного вопроса, то можно заметить `php`, иииии.... как бы всё, сокеты пока)

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach я не спец в php но поверхностный гуглёж не безнадежен вроде как http://socketo.me/ + https://github.com/licson0729/libSSE-php

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, Вопрос частично по этой теме: Какой вариант лучше использовать, для обновления контента (пример, обновление мониторинга сервера в течение n-секунд (допустим 1-5сек))?

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 если супер оперативного обновления не требуется - polling подойдет, sse обеспечит оперативность. А вообще-то подойдет любой вариант, выбирайте что легче реализовать именно Вам

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, спасибо, думаю попробовать первый вариант, раз он "самый простой", думаю особой оперативности не нужно, к тому же "общаться" придётся с php. Ещё раз спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Сам делал подобное: с помощью ajax. Просто ставишь интервал - минуты будет достаточно, а работнику выводишь сообщение - ваше задание будет проверено в течении n-минут. За сервер не бойся, тестируй и смотри нагрузку.

Comment: Ну как-то минута мне кажется многовато. Вот допустим взять вконтакте. Когда новое сообщение появляется, то счётчик сообщений обновляется сразу же. Неужели там тоже запросы делаются постоянно к серверу?

Comment: Предполагаю в сообщениях другая система. У нас в проекте сокет крутится, который делает всю работу. Как вариант, использовать сокет.

Comment: Я про сокет слышал, и пытался копать в этом направлении. Но простого примера не нашёл. Не подскажите где про него почитать чтобы было простым языком как для чайников?

Comment: В PHP юзал Workerman:
https://github.com/walkor/Workerman
Для связи фронта и back:
https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets
Со стороны фронта: когда работник сделал задание и нажал на кнопку отправить - открыл сокет, отправил на сервер, обработал ответ. Со стороны серверы - получил задание, отправил менеджеру. + в менеджера сокет должен быть постоянно открытым