# Технологии вместо ajax-запроса каждую секунду на сервер

Tags: php, ajax

На данные момент для динамического обновления баланса на счету у пользователя, каждые несколько секунд через ajax на сервер отправляется запрос на выборку баланса из БД.

Есть ли какие-нибудь альтернативы, чтоб не нагружать так сильно сервер? Может ли сам сервер отправить в браузер запрос на обновление? Много слышал про разные технологии по типу вебсокетов, rachet и тд. Но хочется узнать какая технология лучше всего подойдет для такой задачи и желательно с как можно низким уровнем порога входа.

Comment: тут надо более шире смотреть на вопрос. Точнее на то зачем лишь для выборки баланса тюкать сервак аяксом или использовать сокеты? Вот зачем? Если речь лишь о балансе - то это бестолковое действие. Проще на запрос о некому url его дергать или при обновлении страницы. Пока всё выглядит довольно странно.

Comment: Вы понимаете, что для вебсокета нужно держать соединение с сервером открытым. Сервер не может бесконечно много соединений держать.

Comment: Ладно. Могу переформулировать. Мне нужно чтобы страницы обновлялись в режиме реального времени, если определенные значения меняются в БД. Сайт написан на php, и всё автообновление сейчас делается через ajax. Как это можно сделать по-другому?

Comment: websocket или long polling

Comment: еще есть server sent events, я как то писал пост про это - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/943610/188366