# Отслеживание клиентом изменений на сервере

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, reactjs

Допустим у меня есть сервер на node и сайт на react. На нём есть лента постов. Каждый пользователь может добавлять пост на сайт, делая запрос на сервер. Сервер обновляет данные в БД. Если клиент зайдет на сайт, то сервер пришлет ему информацию о текущих постах, но что если они через некоторое время поменяются? Если какой-то другой человек добавит на сайт пост, то как оповестить других людей, что информация о постах обновлена?

В голове у меня было 2 варианта решения. Первый предполагает проверку состояния сервера с клиента каждые N секунд. Если изменения будут, то сервер их пришлет в ответ запроса. Но этот вариант мне кажется не рациональным, так как каждый клиент должен будет кидать постоянно запросы с проверкой. Второй - сервер как-то запоминает адреса клиентов, у которых до сих пор открыт сайт, и при изменении данных кидает им пакет. Как реализовать первый вариант для меня понятно, но вот как должен выглядеть в виде кода второй вариант я не предполагаю

Comment: для этих целей подходитя вебсокеты. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws    https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/943610/188366

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно смотреть в сторону websocket
Браузер и сервер устанавливают соединение и обмениваются сообщениями в режиме реального времени.

Попробуйте использовать https://socket.io/